# Text streaming with RTMP?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, video-streaming

- I'm trying to get the output of a bash file to an RTMP stream.
- I've successfully done it with FFMPEG using a filter, but the stream stops at Random intervals.
- I assume that it's FFMPEG reading NULL data from the file.
- I already write another file "output.txt", delete " input.txt" (which FFMPEG is reading) and rename "output.txt" to "input.txt".

Is there any way to do it more atomic in bash so it will work? Or is there a more elegant way to turn a changing text (max one time per second) to an FFMPEG stream?
Here is my current script:

```
ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -i /dev/zero -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vcodec h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 -b:v 2500k -qscale:v 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k -vf "drawtext=fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:fontsize=15:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf:textfile=input.txt:x=0:y=0:reload=1" -f flv "rtmp://example.com/key"
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of your script?

Comment: @belwood added it